# How can I simulate all mouse and keyboard events in Qt that works on Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

Problem: I have a device that send to me some commands (e.g: 1,2,3,...), i want simulate mouse and keyboard events according to received commands in Both Linux OS and Windows OS.

I worked with `bool QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event, int priority = Qt::NormalEventPriority)` but i don't know what receiver pass to it and i has problem with `MouseMove` action with it.

I found this [help](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput) that works good in linux OS, but i have problem with this help approach in Windows OS.
Is there any approach that works in both OS?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set mouse position by :

```
QCursor::setPos(QPoint(10,10));
```

Also mouse click simulation could be done by :

```
QMouseEvent * event1 = new QMouseEvent ((QEvent::MouseButtonPress), QPoint(10,10),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::NoModifier   );

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)myWidget,(QEvent *)event1);

QMouseEvent * event2 = new QMouseEvent ((QEvent::MouseButtonRelease), QPoint(10,10),
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::LeftButton,
    Qt::NoModifier   );

qApp->postEvent((QObject*)myWidget,(QEvent *)event2);
```

Sending a key event to a widget is like :

```
QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent (myWidget, event);
```